# Java, change size of Frame when Panel changes size, homework

Tags: java, swing

Newbie, so bear with me. I am writing a Sokoban game in Java, I got the game up and going but I am having problems with pack(). I want my frame to resize itself depending on the size of the level, different levels have different sizes. The panel is being painted correctly for the different sizes, so if I just maximize the frame then everything is good, but how do I invoke pack() to automatically resize the frame? I tried to put pack() in my Main method, but I suspect the solution is not so simple (probably the way I have structured my program does not help either). Putting pack() in the Main method produces the image attached, a very small rectangle with basically just the min,max and close buttons.[image: frame]

The recommended solution that I would like to implement is as follows:

write your Sokoban constructor so that it takes the surrounding JFrame as a reference parameter that your object then remembers in a field. Then after you change the preferred size of your Sokoban component, call the method pack for this stored surrounding JFrame.

I have attached the code for my constructor and Main method.

```
public class Sokoban extends JPanel {

LevelReader lReader = new LevelReader();      
private static final int SQUARESIZE = 50;  // square size in pixels
int currentLevel = 0;
int height = 0;
int width = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Contents [][] mapArray;

public Sokoban(String fileName) {
    lReader.readLevels(fileName);
    initLevel(currentLevel);
    KeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener();
    addKeyListener(listener);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setFocusable(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sokoban");
    Sokoban sokoban = new Sokoban("m1.txt");
    frame.add(sokoban);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: This probably wont solve your problem but it is good practice to use `frame.setVisible(true);` after you add everything to frame, so try to move it after `setDefaultCloseOperation`.

Comment: Also, you should use `jframe.getContentPane().add()`? instead of just `add`.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks, what is the advantage of     jframe.getContentPane().add() over simply     add?

Comment: There's no benefit, `add` just calls `getContentPane` in the background, but it makes it more clear to others that you are actually adding controls to the contentpane, and not the rootpane for instance. You can read about it in the docs for jframe, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> write your Sokoban constructor so that it takes the surrounding JFrame as a reference parameter that your object then remembers in a field. Then after you change the preferred size of your Sokoban component, call the method pack for this stored surrounding JFrame

### Answer was updated to use [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as suggested by @mKorbel (thanks for tip, code looks cleaner now)

What your fried was trying to tell is to create something like this (I removed your code that wasn't necessary in this example)

```
class Sokoban extends JPanel {

    private JFrame frame;

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Dimension dimension;

        public MyAction(Dimension dimension) {
            this.dimension = dimension;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //we will pack only when dimensions will need to change
            if (!getPreferredSize().equals(dimension)) {
                setPreferredSize(dimension);
                frame.pack();
            }
        }
    }

    public Sokoban(String fileName, JFrame tframe) {
        this.frame = tframe;
        setFocusable(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setBackground(Color.red);
        add(new JLabel("press A, S, D"));

        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a'), "typed a");
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s'), "typed s");
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('d'), "typed d");

        getActionMap().put("typed a", new MyAction(new Dimension(100, 100)));
        getActionMap().put("typed s", new MyAction(new Dimension(200, 100)));
        getActionMap().put("typed d", new MyAction(new Dimension(100, 200)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sokoban");
        Sokoban sokoban = new Sokoban("m1.txt", frame);

        frame.setContentPane(sokoban);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In constructor `public Sokoban(String fileName, JFrame tframe)` you need to pass reference to frame that will contain your Sokoban panel. You will need to store object from that reference somewhere in your class, like in class field `private JFrame frame;`.

Now thanks to that reference whenever you change size of your panel you can use it to change size of frame containing that panel by invoking `frame.pack()` and make it to adapt to new size.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to implement the solution exactly as you suggested but I was able to use your idea to solve my problem. I couldn't get it to work using setPreferredSize, but I got it to work using setSize. I think setPreferredSize is preferred to setSize? Also, why are you using boolean needResize? why not just call frame.pack anyway without first setting needResize and then checking if needResize was set?

Comment: @user1894469 I am not sure why, but sometimes when frame didn't need resizing and I called `pack` it prevented next resizing. That is why i used flag to check if resizing was necessary. Is `setPreferredSize` preferred to `setSize`? I don't know. I couldn't achieve resizing with setSize+pack so I used setPreferredSize instead. Anyway main purpose of my answer was to show idea of passing reference to Frame in Sokoban constructor, rest was not that important.